# Split single column into two based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` that looks like this:

```
Supervisor  Score
Bill    Pass
Bill    Pass
Susan   Fail
Susan   Fail
Susan   Fail
```

I would like to do some aggregates (such as getting the % of pass by supervisor) and would like to split up the Score column so all the Pass are in one column and all the Fail are in another column.  Like this:

```
Supervisor  Pass    Fail
Bill          0      1
Bill          0      1
Susan         1      0
Susan         1      0
Susan         1      0
```

Any ideas?  Would a simple `groupby` work by grouping both the supervisor and score columns and getting a count of Score?

Comment: Why use 0/1 instead of a boolean? What are you actually asking for here? Are you asking how to indicate pass/fail with a boolean, or how to get those various metrics? In any case, it looks like you need a `groupby`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

Removes any columns you specify from your DataFrame in favor of N dummy columns with the default naming convention `'OrigName_UniqueVal'`. Specifying empty strings for the prefix and separator gives you column headers of only the unique values.

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Score'], prefix_sep='', prefix='')

  Supervisor  Fail  Pass
0       Bill     0     1
1       Bill     0     1
2      Susan     1     0
3      Susan     1     0
4      Susan     1     0
```

---

If in the end you just want % of each category by supervisor then you don't really need the dummies. You can `groupby`. I use a `reindex` to ensure the resulting DataFrame has each category represented for each Supervisor.

```
(df.groupby(['Supervisor']).Score.value_counts(normalize=True)
   .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Supervisor.unique(), df.Score.unique()]))
   .fillna(0))

#Bill   Pass    1.0
#       Fail    0.0
#Susan  Pass    0.0
#       Fail    1.0
#Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I forget `get_dummies` here, it's a great method. I guess this method will use pivot table internally and will have similar efficiency

Comment: This worked but is there a way I could get the column names so I can chart it out?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you want [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) + [`DataFrmae.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
new_df = df[['Supervisor']].join(df.pivot_table(columns = 'Score',
                                                index = df.index,
                                                values ='Supervisor',
                                                aggfunc='count',
                                                fill_value=0))
print(new_df)

  Supervisor  Fail  Pass
0       Bill     0     1
1       Bill     0     1
2      Susan     1     0
3      Susan     1     0
4      Susan     1     0
```

---

For the output expect:

```
new_df = df[['Supervisor']].join(df.pivot_table(columns = 'Score',
                                                index = df.index,
                                                values ='Supervisor',
                                                aggfunc='count',
                                                fill_value=0)
                                    .eq(0)
                                    .astype(int))
print(new_df)
  Supervisor  Fail  Pass
0       Bill     1     0
1       Bill     1     0
2      Susan     0     1
3      Susan     0     1
4      Susan     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**Let's try this one**

df=pd.DataFrame({'Supervisor':['Bill','Bill','Susan','Susan','Susan'],
                'Score':['Pass','Pass','Fail','Fail','Fail']}).set_index('Supervisor')


pd.get_dummies(df['Score'])

PANDAS 100 tricks
For More Pandas trick refer following : https://www.kaggle.com/python10pm/pandas-100-tricks
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the df you want you can do it like this:

```
df["Pass"] = df["Score"].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == "Pass" else 1)
df["Fail"] = df["Score"].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == "Fail" else 1)
```